# About spaces $\Bbb R^n/\!\sim$ in which certain coordinate permutations do not matter.

Tags: general-topology, permutations, equivalence-relations, symmetric-groups, quotient-spaces

Let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on the permutations of $(1,...,n)$. I thought about the topological spaces $\Bbb R^n/\!\sim$, i.e. $\Bbb R^n$ with standard topology after associating certain permutations $\sigma$ of the indices. More precisely:

$$(x_1,...,x_n)\sim_{\Bbb R^n}(x_{\sigma(1)},...,x_{\sigma(n)})\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad (1,...,n)\sim(\sigma(1),...,\sigma(n)).$$

> **Example**: $\Bbb R^n/S_n:=\Bbb R^n/\!\sim$ with $\sim$ associating *all* permutations, is the space in which the order of the coordinates does not matter.

I made the following observations:

- $\Bbb R^n/S_n\cong \Bbb R^n_+=\Bbb R^{n-1}\times\{x\in\Bbb R\mid x\ge 0\}$, the $n$-dimensional half-space. This can be seen by associating $\Bbb R^n/S_n$ with the subset $\{(x_1,...,x_n)\mid x_1\le\cdots\le x_n\}\subset\Bbb R^n$ with increasing coordinates.
- $\Bbb C^n/S_n\cong \Bbb C^n$ (a homeomorphism is given by [Vièta's map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) which associates *unordered* roots with *ordered* coefficients of polynomials). This can be expressed as $\Bbb R^{2n}/\!\sim\;\cong \Bbb R^{2n}$ where $\sim$ only associates permutations in which certain consecutive pairs of indices permute in lockstep, e.g.

$$(\color{red}{1,2},\color{blue}{3,4})\sim(\color{blue}{3,4},\color{red}{1,2})\qquad\text{but not}\qquad (1,2,\color{red}3,\color{blue}4)\sim(1,2,\color{blue}3,\color{red}4).$$

> **Question**: I was wondering what different spaces can emerge from $\Bbb R^n/\!\sim$. I would conjecture that it only can be $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb R^n_+$. In this case I was wondering whether there is a simple characterization of the relations $\sim$ which generate either one.

Comment: I would first try to understand what happens when $G$ is a transitive subgroup of $S_n$...

Comment: @ClémentGuérin Now as you say it, it probably makes no sense to have an equivalence relation if the group action is not transitive, right? I should probably take the transitive closure anyway.